# isotope callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Isotope provides two places where you can supply callback functions:

```
container.isotope({
    itemSelector: itemSelector,
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    onLayout: function() {alert('onLayout callback')}

}, function() {alert('anon callback')});
```

I don't know what the difference between these two are - they both seem to be called exactly once, after the layout has completed. I've looked through the docs, but all I can find is

> Similiar to a callback, onLayout is a function that will be triggered after every time an Isotope instance runs through its layout logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/blob/master/jquery.isotope.js), there is no difference. Three callback functions may be called when layout completes: the one passed in the final argument to `isotope()`, the one passed in the `onLayout` option and the one passed in the `complete` member of the `animationOptions` option.

The relevant parts of the source are:

```
// [...]    
} else if ( callback || onLayout || animOpts.complete ) {
    // has callback
    var isCallbackTriggered = false,
        // array of possible callbacks to trigger
        callbacks = [ callback, onLayout, animOpts.complete ],
        instance = this;
    triggerCallbackNow = true;
    // trigger callback only once
    callbackFn = function() {
        if ( isCallbackTriggered ) {
            return;
        }
        var hollaback;
        for (var i=0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; i++) {
            hollaback = callbacks[i];
            if ( typeof hollaback === 'function' ) {
                hollaback.call( instance.element, $elems );
            }
        }
        isCallbackTriggered = true;
    };
    // [...]
}
```

As you can see, an array is built with the three potential callbacks, and `callbackFn()` calls each one in sequence if it's a function.

Comment: An impressively irrefutable answer, well done. I wonder why 3 different ways were provided to do the same thing? Seems like poor API design, though there may be historical (or other) reasons I'm unaware of.